# Icons and images in PyQt5 do not display under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pyqt5, ubuntu-18.04

I installed PyQt5 from Pypi on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and am attempting to work my way through a tutorial. Most things work fine except when icons or images are to be displayed. For icons, the space needed to display it is reserved and you can interact with the space as if the icon image was there but no image displays.

For images, the space is reserved with the correct dimensions but no image is displayed.

This implies to me that PyQt5 is finding the icons and images and is doing everything except actually displaying them. A sample script is included here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self) -> None:
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('WiseOldBirdLogo.png')

        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pixmap')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get the icons and images to display.

Comment: Hello! I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you find a solution for it? Thanks!